# How to parse SOAP response using Java API

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, automation

I'm executing the SOAP web services using Karate API and its generating SOAP-based response.

Then I write the response into an XML file using Java Code - File has been created successfully.

Here's the sample SOAP Response Content which I have...

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:getMbrWksMembershipDetailsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.xxxxxxx.com/services/customersummary">
         <ns4:WksMembershipSummaryResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.xxxxxxx.com/services/customersummary/contract" xmlns:ns3="http://www.xxxxx.com/eom" xmlns:ns4="http://www.xxxx.com/services/customersummary">
            <ns2:customerSummary>
               <ns2:address>
                  <ns2:city>SOUTH CHESTERFIELD</ns2:city>
                  <ns2:country>USA</ns2:country>
                  <ns2:isoCountryCode>US</ns2:isoCountryCode>
                  <ns2:line1>9998, N. MICHIGAN ROAD.</ns2:line1>
                  <ns2:postalCode>23834</ns2:postalCode>
                  <ns2:state>VA</ns2:state>
               </ns2:address>
               <ns2:allowPasswordChange>true</ns2:allowPasswordChange>
               <ns2:arpMember>false</ns2:arpMember>
               <ns2:brandCode>RCI</ns2:brandCode>
               <ns2:brandId>1</ns2:brandId>
               <ns2:companyCode>RCI</ns2:companyCode>
               ..........
```

I have written a java code for fetching the tag value e.g. firstName. This is Java method.

```
public static String getTagValue(String strResponseFile, String strTagName)
    {
        String fileLoc = "D:\\getMembershipDetailsResponse.xml";
      try
      {
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
          dbf.setNamespaceAware(false); 

          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
          **Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader(fileLoc)));** 
          XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath(); 

          Node n1 = (Node)xpath.evaluate("//customerSummary/brandCode", doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODE); 
          System.out.println(n1.getNodeValue()); 

          Node c1 = (Node)xpath.evaluate("//customerSummary/firstName",doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODE); 
          System.out.println(c1.getNodeValue());
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {

      }
        return "";
    }
```

I'm getting NULL in the above **bold** line of Java code. Can you please give your valuable suggestion on that to resolve the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: First find out what is unexpectedly null and fix that.  Most likely the file is not there.

Comment: Also empty catch blocks are time bombs waiting to explode.

Comment: Hi, File is present in the given path. And its not even throwing any error during runtime. Document object has NULL. Don't understand why...

Comment: Still I'm not able to find the solution... :( Any body help on this?

Comment: Hello...no one having an answer for this issue...